# Handling Deeply nested Json Objects using useState in Reactjs

Tags: json, reactjs

Am trying to get value from nested json. but got '**undefined**' error. when i display the same object in console, it works fine. I want to fetch particular field from nested json object.

here is the json output from api, i want to fetch userid, name and verified fields from below json

```
{
status: true,
user:
{
    id: 11362
    phone: "+918971557357"
    name: "Sagar pawar"
    email: null
    bio: null
    address: null
    date_of_birth: null
    token: "EMAWdBl3LDjl1X5veo6VvZBKfgQns5wTFXKWjIh9w4VKKXlclRo5ZBlWaJUBS5ImaVZANN9DlHSbFWquObaW1FIJLVGPqFLWKoPEzKLvZAJakhoTxg5TRTjVtLEVz9R9zAbocwF7dmRdI4GCAMlJdtKOEZAUuOcf6AZD"
    image: ""
    role: "user"
    notification_cleared: {date: "2019-12-28 11:42:34.899503", timezone_type: 3, timezone: "UTC"}
    deleted_by: null
    blocked: 0
    verified: 0
    }
}
```

and this is the fetch function i tried.

```
fetch(url, options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(body => console.log("Data Response", body))
      .then(data => {
        const jsonobj = data.user.id;
        console.log("User ID:", jsonobj);
      })
```

and this one i have tried.

```
const [responseUserId, setUserId] = useState(userId);
...

fetch(url, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res =>
      setUserId({ userId: res.user['id'] })
    )
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You never seem to use that data. Where is jsonobj used? Do you have another .then (which is now receiving a promise of undefined)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @jonrsharpe i am new to react and couldn't understand how to do it.

Comment: How to do *what*? You mention useState, which isn't shown in the question. Give a [mcve].

Comment: @jonrsharpe, edited my question and added code sample that i have tried

Comment: And what's the *problem* with that? You mention an error, but you haven't shown it. One thing that seems suspicious is setting the state prop to an object; maybe the initial value is the same, but *you haven't shown that either*. Re-read [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost. In your fetch function when you log data, in the second then you don't return any data, so in the third then your callback argument is undefined. After `console.log("Data Response", body)`, you should add `return body`, so it get's passed down as `data` in your next `then` statement.

Second, your id is a string(or number, it doesn't matter). So your `responseUserId` will be a string. So when setting the state with `useState` you don't need to pass in an object, just pass the value. Like this : `setUserId(res.user['id'])`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

i create a simple fetch request and setUserId just like you want and it works.

the problem is you use 3 then methods you only need 2.
in the third then data is undefind but in second you have what you need.

```
.then(res => res.json())
.then(body => console.log("Data Response", body))
.then(data => {
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-mestorf-o43s1

it is so simple i hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

I will use your last example of a functional component with `useState`:

You initialize `responseUserId` with `userId`. Given the code you provided, that should fail to compile, because `userId` is not defined. Give it a value, like `null`, or `0` or an empty string.

If you return an object with only one property, you probably don't need the object data type. In my example `data.userId` and consequently `responseUserId` is of type Number.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [responseUserId, setResponseUserId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1';
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setResponseUserId(data.userId))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }, []);

  return responseUserId && <h3>{responseUserId}</h3>;
}
```